# TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function thrown only on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, safari, tablesorter

I am receiving the following error code when trying to load tablesorter:

```
"TypeError: $(".tablesorter").tablesorter is not a function. (In '$(".tablesorter").tablesorter({sortList:[[0,1]]})','$(".tablesorter").tablesorter'is undefined)
```

Running the code on desktop browsers works perfectly (Chrome, FF, IE), and works on android phones.

Here is a fiddle (which does happen to work on the ipad): https://jsfiddle.net/cvuca2mx/

I am loading the files in the following order on my server:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.25.0/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/1.1.1/introjs.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/1.1.1/intro.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/commonUI/commonUI.css" />
<script src="/commonUI/commonJS.js"></script>
```

I have verified my files are only being loaded a single time, as this was a common issue with other individuals. If I directly place the CDN's JS for tablesorter into my commonJS file, and remove the call to the CDN, the iPad works perfectly fine.

Has anyone else experienced similar issues on the ipad, or have any suggestions?

Comment: Try loading commonJS immediately after jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that didn't resolve the issue. The iPad still had the same issue with tablesorter.

Comment: What does the initialization code look like? Is `jQuery.noConflict()` being used anywhere? Is jQuery being loaded more than once?

Answer (score 0):

The jquery.tablesorter.js file is updated by vendor.

new class is "tablesorterPager" and not "tablesorter"

as at updated jquery.tablesorter.js

`"(function($) {
    $.extend({
        **tablesorterPager**: new function() { ......"`

Regards